# Filter on specific classes in the inbox using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I need to get all emails of the class MeetingCancellation from an inbox of a shared mailbox. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to filter on the classes with EWS Managed API.

I need to filter, to get this piece of code working and not throw an exception every time, it tries to process a normal email:

```
List<MeetingCancellation> findResultsList = findResults.Select<dynamic, MeetingCancellation>(x => { return ConvertItemHelper(x); }).ToList();
```

I can't use the `GetType()` method, because `findResults` is an Object of the `FindItemsResults<Item>`class (=> I can't find out, wether it is a MeetingCancellation or not).

I'm coding in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better to just use a SearchFilter to limit whats returned from the server to just the Meeting cancelcation eg something like

```
 SearchFilter sf1 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Canceled");
 FindItemsResults<Item> Results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,sf1, ItemViewObj);
```

also

```
findResults.Where(x => x.ItemClass == "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Canceled");
```

Should work

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I just used the `SearchFilter` now.